# How to implement object rotation animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, rotation

There is a falling balls code https://jsfiddle.net/d1e8x7wk/,

which is generated using canvas

Code also added to this editor

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  //---------------------------------------
  // Set up ball options
  //---------------------------------------

  const imgBalls = [
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png',
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png',
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png',
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png',
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png',
    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/basketball-2500972-2093649.png'
  ]

  let ballCount = imgBalls.length, // How many balls
    DAMPING = 0.4, // Damping
    GRAVITY = 0.01, // Gravity strength
    SPEED = 5, // Ball speed
    ballAdditionTime = 100, // How fast are balls added
    ballSrc = imgBalls, // Ball image source
    topOffset = 400, // Adjust this for initial ball spawn point
    xOffset = 0, // left offset
    yOffset = 0, // bottom offset
    ballDensity = 20, // How dense are the balls
    ball_1_size = 200, // Ball 1 size
    ball_2_size = 180, // Ball 2 size
    ball_3_size = 62, // Ball 6 size
    canvasWidth = 1500, // Canvas width
    canvasHeight = 1000, // Canvas height
    stackBall = true, // Stack the balls (or false is overlap)
    ballsLoaded = 0,
    stopAnimation = false;


  //---------------------------------------
  // Canvas globals
  //---------------------------------------

  let canvas,
    ctx,
    TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2,
    balls = [],
    vel_x,
    vel_y;

  let rect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: canvasWidth,
    h: canvasHeight
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // do the animation
  //---------------------------------------

  window.requestAnimFrame =
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, ballAdditionTime);
    };

  //---------------------------------------
  // set up the ball
  //---------------------------------------

  const Ball = function(x, y, radius, num) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.px = x;
    this.py = y;
    this.fx = 0;
    this.fy = 0;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.num = num;
    this.angle = 0;

    // Different ball sizes
    let random = Math.round(Math.random() * imgBalls.length)

    if (random === 0) {
      this.width = ball_1_size;
      this.height = ball_1_size;
      if (stackBall) {
        this.radius = ball_1_size / 2;
      }
    } else if (random === 1 || random === 2) {
      this.width = ball_2_size;
      this.height = ball_2_size;
      if (stackBall) {
        this.radius = ball_2_size / 2;
      }
    } else {
      this.width = ball_3_size;
      this.height = ball_3_size;
      if (stackBall) {
        this.radius = ball_3_size / 2;
      }
    }

    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Apply the physics
  //---------------------------------------

  Ball.prototype.apply_force = function(delta) {
    delta *= delta;
    this.fy += GRAVITY;
    this.x += this.fx * delta;
    this.y += this.fy * delta;
    this.fx = this.fy = 0;
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Newtonian motion algorithm
  //---------------------------------------

  Ball.prototype.velocity = function() {
    var nx = this.x * 2 - this.px;
    var ny = this.y * 2 - this.py;
    this.px = this.x;
    this.py = this.y;
    this.x = nx;
    this.y = ny;
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Ball prototype
  //---------------------------------------

  Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = imgBalls[this.num];
    if (stackBall) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        img,
        this.x - this.radius - xOffset,
        this.y - this.radius - xOffset,
        this.width,
        this.height
      );
    } else {
      ctx.drawImage(
        img,
        this.x - xOffset,
        this.y - yOffset,
        this.width,
        this.height
      );
    }
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // resolve collisions (ball on ball)
  //---------------------------------------

  let resolve_collisions = function(ip) {
    let i = balls.length;
    while (i--) {
      let ball_1 = balls[i];
      let n = balls.length;
      while (n--) {
        if (n == i) continue;
        let ball_2 = balls[n];
        let diff_x = ball_1.x - ball_2.x;
        let diff_y = ball_1.y - ball_2.y;
        let length = diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y;
        let dist = Math.sqrt(length);
        let real_dist = dist - (ball_1.radius + ball_2.radius);

        if (real_dist < 0) {
          let vel_x1 = ball_1.x - ball_1.px;
          let vel_y1 = ball_1.y - ball_1.py;
          let vel_x2 = ball_2.x - ball_2.px;
          let vel_y2 = ball_2.y - ball_2.py;
          let depth_x = diff_x * (real_dist / dist);
          let depth_y = diff_y * (real_dist / dist);
          ball_1.x -= depth_x * 0.5;
          ball_1.y -= depth_y * 0.5;
          ball_2.x += depth_x * 0.5;
          ball_2.y += depth_y * 0.5;

          if (ip) {
            let pr1 = (DAMPING * (diff_x * vel_x1 + diff_y * vel_y1)) / length;
            let pr2 = (DAMPING * (diff_x * vel_x2 + diff_y * vel_y2)) / length;
            vel_x1 += pr2 * diff_x - pr1 * diff_x;
            vel_x2 += pr1 * diff_x - pr2 * diff_x;
            vel_y1 += pr2 * diff_y - pr1 * diff_y;
            vel_y2 += pr1 * diff_y - pr2 * diff_y;
            ball_1.px = ball_1.x - vel_x1;
            ball_1.py = ball_1.y - vel_y1;
            ball_2.px = ball_2.x - vel_x2;
            ball_2.py = ball_2.y - vel_y2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Bounce off the walls
  //---------------------------------------

  let check_walls = function() {
    let i = balls.length;
    while (i--) {
      let ball = balls[i];

      if (ball.x < ball.radius) {
        let vel_x = ball.px - ball.x;
        ball.x = ball.radius;
        ball.px = ball.x - vel_x * DAMPING;
      } else if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {
        vel_x = ball.px - ball.x;
        ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
        ball.px = ball.x - vel_x * DAMPING;
      }

      // Ball is new. So don't do collision detection until it hits the canvas. (with an offset to stop it snapping)
      if (ball.y > 100) {
        if (ball.y < ball.radius) {
          let vel_y = ball.py - ball.y;
          ball.y = ball.radius;
          ball.py = ball.y - vel_y * DAMPING;
        } else if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
          vel_y = ball.py - ball.y;
          ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius;
          ball.py = ball.y - vel_y * DAMPING;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Add a ball to the canvas
  //---------------------------------------

  let add_ball = function(num) {
    let x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    let y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    let r = 30 + Math.random() * ballDensity;

    let diff_x = x;
    let diff_y = y;
    let dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

    balls.push(new Ball(x, y, r, num));
  };


  //---------------------------------------
  // iterate balls
  //---------------------------------------

  let update = function() {
    let iter = 1;
    let delta = SPEED / iter;

    while (iter--) {
      let i = balls.length;
      while (i--) {
        balls[i].apply_force(delta);
        balls[i].velocity();
      }

      resolve_collisions();
      check_walls();

      i = balls.length;
      while (i--) {
        balls[i].velocity();
        let ball = balls[i];
      }

      resolve_collisions();
      check_walls();
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    i = balls.length;
    while (i--) {
      balls[i].draw(ctx);
    }

    requestAnimFrame(update);
  };

  //---------------------------------------
  // Set up the canvas object
  //---------------------------------------

  function doBalls() {
    stopAnimation = false;
    canvas = document.getElementById("balls");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let $canvasDiv = document.querySelector(".section");

    function respondCanvas() {
      canvas.height = $canvasDiv.clientHeight;
      canvas.width = $canvasDiv.clientWidth;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    respondCanvas();

    ballAdd();
  }

  function ballAdd() {
    let count = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
      addBallTimer();
    }, 100);

    let addBallTimer = function() {
      add_ball(count % ballCount);
      count++;

      if (count === ballCount) {
        stopTimer();
      }
    };

    let stopTimer = function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };

    update();
  }

  doBalls();



});
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <canvas id="balls"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a rotation the balls

```
const Ball = function(x, y, radius, num) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.px = x;
        this.py = y;
        this.fx = 0;
        this.fy = 0;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.num = num;
        this.angle = 0;

        // Different ball sizes
        let random = Math.round(Math.random() * imgBalls.length)

        if (random === 0) {
  this.width = ball_1_size;
  this.height = ball_1_size;
  if (stackBall) {
    this.radius = ball_1_size / 2;
  }
} else if (random === 1 || random === 2) {
  this.width = ball_2_size;
  this.height = ball_2_size;
  if (stackBall) {
    this.radius = ball_2_size / 2;
  }
} else {
  this.width = ball_3_size;
  this.height = ball_3_size;
  if (stackBall) {
    this.radius = ball_3_size / 2;
  }
}

        ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
      };
```

After reading the information,

I wrote this code, but it does not work for me

```
ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

I must have misunderstood how to do this, tell me how to properly rotate the balls

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your ball sizes (or radius) is overly hardcoded. Also by just doing `angle = 0;` and then simply:`ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);` there's not much you could expect - regarding *rotation*... Also, why the magic number `100` in `if (ball.y > 100) {`?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan sorry i'm just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to

1. increase the angle at some point in your code
2. apply a rotation transform to rotate around each ball center before each drawImage call

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(+this.x, +this.y);
ctx.rotate(this.angle++ * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-this.x, -this.y);
ctx.drawImage
ctx.restore()
```

`ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` is called to restore the canvas transform after each draw call.

Please read
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate#rotating_a_shape_around_its_center
for details on applying transforms to Canvas.

Comment: Thanks. Rotating work - https://jsfiddle.net/cjehg23x/. Can you please tell me how to stop the rotation so that they do not rotate constantly?

Comment: You will need to find a condition when they should stop rotating - e.g. "when they lie on the ground". Try to figure out what is the y coordinate when they lie on the ground and replace the unconditional `this.angle++` with  `if(this.y > somevalue) this.angle++`.

Comment: or do somethting like `if(this.velocity > 0) this.angle++`

Comment: Thanks, but  not working https://jsfiddle.net/e4t3uqp5/ - ```this.velocity()>0``` or  ```if(this.y +  this.radius - yOffset > canvas.height)``` -

Comment: I'm most likely doing something wrong

Comment: was looking into the physics code but didn't understand it. where is the velocity state for each ball? if the velocity state is explicity it can be used to stop rotation when velocity is below a threshold.